# Navigating to subsite adds Pages/Page.aspx to the URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, aspx, pages

I have various sitecollections and they are behaving different. One of them, when I navigate to one of its subsites, it shows the Welcome.aspx but the URL remains unchanged, only with https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecol1/subsite.

The other ones, even if I type the same, it automatically changes to the following:
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecol2/subsite/Pages/MyWelcome.aspx.

At site settings, both have as welcome page the entire Url (with the aspx) and I tried changing the default welcome page and setting back again and did not work.

I am wondering what is causing this and if there is any setting to modify it.

Thanks

Comment: Is one site collection modern and one classic?  Or are they the same?

Comment: No, they are all classic